# How To Use Eclipse Help In a Wizard

Tags: eclipse-plugin, jface

I found two ways to allegedly make the help work for an Eclipse wizard.

The first is to set `setHelpAvailable(true)` on my instance of `Wizard` and let the `WizardPage` override the method:

```java
public void performHelp() { 
  PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getHelpSystem().displayHelp(CONTEXT_ID); 
}
```

It displays a help button without an icon next to the "Back" button, but the method `performHelp` is never called.

The second way is to set it on the `TrayDialog` directly like this:

```java
WizardDialog dialog = new WizardDialog(myShell, myWizard);
dialog.create();
WorkbenchHelp.setHelp(dialog.getShell(), CONTEXT_ID);
dialog.setHelpAvailable(true);
dialog.open();
```

This displays a button with an icon on the bottom left, but nothing happens when I click it.

The help system is set up (quiet a feat with the documentation, if I say so myself), but I can't figure out how to get either of these solutions to work. And I wonder if one of them should preferred over the other?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Just for completeness sake: In my case the problem had nothing to do with the sparsely documented help feature, but with the fact that Eclipse Mars can't Hot Code Replace anymore.

Comment: This is wrong. Make sure your launch configuration for debugging the Java code actually uses a JRE that is capable of hot code replacement. Check your workspace preferences under Java -> Debug to enable error messages for hot code replacement failing, so you avoid missing this situation in the future.

Comment: @Bananeweizen It is enabled and has been for a long time. And I know Eclipse usually can HCR, after updating to Mars it just fails for half of my workspaces. (And I totally dig your name!)

Answer (score 2):

With the `WizardDialog` just call

```java
 dialog.setHelpAvailable(true);
```

In the `createControl` method of each `WizardPage` call the help system `setHelp`:

```java
public void createControl(Composite parent)
{
  Composite composite = new Composite(parent, SWT.NONE);

  PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getHelpSystem().setHelp(composite, "help id");

  ... other code
```